# Drupal function basic usage

Tags: php, drupal

I was learning drupal and found like using

```
drupal_add_js(
array('philquotes' =>
array("json_url" => $json_url)), 'setting');
```

and he says that it get converted to

```
Drupal.settings.philquotes.json_url
```

and this is used to pass php variable to JS.  I got a doubt that is it just used to create a JS variable in PHP so that it can be accessible in JS or any other meaning is there in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drupal_add_js` function can be used to add a setting, but can also be used to add a file or inline javascript.  Drupal has some good documentation in its API.  See the `drupal_add_js` documentation at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7